# Leaflet Zoom Button in Popup

Tags: javascript, leaflet, zooming

I am trying to add a 'zoom to' button in a leaflet popup that will pan and zoom to the feature when clicked. I can't figure out exactly how to do this with the code below (I know I am massacring the code):

```
function getLoc(e){
    map.setView(e.latlng);
    }
        
        // Load Mile Castles
        $.ajax({url:'load_milecastles.php',
               success: function(response){
                   
                   
                       
                   jsnParks = JSON.parse(response);
                   lyrParks = L.geoJSON(jsnParks, 
                                { pointToLayer: function(feature,latlng){return L.marker(latlng,{icon: redMarker});}, 
                                  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                                layer.bindPopup(
                       "<center><h4><b>"+feature.properties.full_name+"</b></h4></center>" +
                       "<button onclick= 'getLoc(e)'>Zoom</button>");
                      }
                 }).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code with:

```
function getLoc(latlng){
    map.setView(JSON.parse(latlng));
}

var latlngStr = JSON.stringify([layer.getLatLng().lat,layer.getLatLng().lng]);
layer.bindPopup("<center><h4><b>"+feature.properties.full_name+"</b></h4></center>" +
                       "<button onclick= 'getLoc(\""+latlngStr+"\")'>Zoom</button>");
```

1. `e` should be a variable but can not readed out because it is a string `onclick='getLoc(e)'`
2. `e` never defined you should add your latlng to the function and not a event
3. Now the latlng is converted to a array and then added as string to the function. When the function is called it convert it back to a array and then the view is moved to the latlng

Comment: That did it! Thank you for the help and the explanation, definitely makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

Use this method, it works for me.

```
var coord;

function getLoc(){
map.setView(coord,13);
}
lyrParks = L.geoJSON(jsnParks, 
                                { pointToLayer: function(feature,latlng){return 
L.marker(latlng,{icon: redMarker});}, 
                                  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                                layer.bindPopup(
                       "<center><h4><b>"+feature.properties.full_name+"</b></h4></center>" +
                       "<button onclick= 'getLoc()'>Zoom</button>");

                                 layer.on('click', function(e){
                        coord =[e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng];
                           }

                         }
                 }).addTo(map);
```

[Zoom button in Popup with leaflet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQVYf.png)